# What is _rootref in phpBB3?

Tags: php, phpbb, phpbb3

I'm a newbie working on some phpBB3 forum code that uses the _rootref function or array.  I'm not sure what it is or what it does.  My google foo attempts have turned up empty.

I'd like to know the file where it is defined and any documentation pertaining to its definition and use.  Thanks.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this? For those not familiar with phpBB3 see: https://www.phpbb.com/about/?sid=bfa84b8ff577ee25437e431b177f7b33

Comment: What are you trying to do and have you looked here: https://www.phpbb.com/support/documentation/3.0/?from=submenu&sid=bfa84b8ff577ee25437e431b177f7b33

Comment: The fact that you're not sure if it's a function or an array indicates that you haven't tried the standard `var_dump`, `print_r`, and `gettype` trio on the variable to try to inspect it. You should try those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The member variable `$_rootref` was [introduced as part of some optimisation work](https://github.com/phpbb/phpbb/commit/0d502f3b07df4c198688d87a08bd6f785db77a1d), and seems to be a reference to the top-level template variables to "reduce the number of hash lookups needed."

Although it's present in the current stable release (3.0.12), it looks like it is being removed as part of the 3.1 branch. This is still under active development, as is [the documentation for migrating from 3.0](https://wiki.phpbb.com/PhpBB3.1).